# Stripe oAuth Token Url Blocked By CORS

Tags: angular, stripe-payments, angular-httpclient

I am trying to setup a Stripe Connect account with my Angular application by using the following docs under step 4.

```
https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standard-accounts
```

I am watching for the code in the return url in the component and then attempting to fetch the user credentials from Stripe using HttpClient.

```
let data = {
    'client_secret':'my-key-hidden-for-security',
    'code' : this._stripeAccountSetupCode,
    'grant_type':'authorization_code'
};
this.httpClient.post('https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token', data).subscribe(response => {
    if(response['statusText']) {
        console.log('ERROR', response);
    } else {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

But for some reason, once this is called I get this response in my console.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token' from origin 'my-localhost-address' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.
```

If stripe is blocking based on CORS Policies, how am I supposed to ever get the credentials? What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you end up finding the solution?

Comment: Couldn't get it to work from client -> connect.stripe.com so ended up just doing client -> my server -> connect.stripe.com.

Answer (score -1):

try setting header value for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to  `*`

Comment: It didnt fix the issue. Any other suggestions?